# Result empty on setting projection for Hibernate criteria

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a join query that I want to put in my programs as hibernate criteria.

```
select a.accountName,a.username,b.name from Account as a , User as b 
where a.id=b.accountId and b.name like '%abc%' and a.username like '%def%'
```

My Criteria is like :

```
Criteria userCriteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
DetachedCriteria accountCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Account.class);
accountCriteria .add(Restrictions.like("name", "%" + def+ "%"));    
accountCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
userCriteria.add(Property.forName("accountId").in(accountCriteria));    
userCriteria.add(Restrictions.eq("username", "%" + abc+ "%"));

List tmpList = userCriteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).list();               
userCriteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
result = userCriteria.list();
```

List tmpList is showing empty. I can list all data before:

```
List tmpList = userCriteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).list();
```

What is problem in this line?

Comment: The HQL uses account.username and user.name, whereas the criteria uses account.name and user.username. Why don't you have an association between these two entities? If your goal is to translate the given HQL to Criteria, you'll need one. The restrictions are diferent as well: we don't know what abc and def values are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the where clause in the query you show us your wrote:

```
b.name like '%abc%' 
a.username like '%def%'
```

but in the code your writing:

```
Restrictions.like("name", "%" + def+ "%")
Restrictions.eq("username", "%" + abc+ "%")
```

If I'm not wrong this creates a where like this:

```
a.name like '%def%' 
b.username == '%abc%'
```

Sarajog